# Function of PPs with predicative complements

Tags: grammar, prepositions, complements, syntactic-analysis, predicative-complements

According to CaGEL* (e.g. p.636 *ff*), prepositions can take predicative complements, as in

[1] She worked as **a waitress**

[2] He passed for **dead**

[3] I took you for **granted**

[4] They left him for **dead**

[5] I love you as **a friend**

Now, I get how these are predicatives, but I'm uncertain as to how to analyse the PPs **as wholes**. I'm thinking they are complements in [1]-[4] and adjunct in [5] – is this correct? And, if so, what kinds of complement are we dealing with in [1]-[4]?

*Huddleston, R., and Pullum, G. K., 2002. *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Comment: I'd say they are all complements of the verbs

Comment: @BillJ I'd say (1, 5) Are adjuncts. They pass the 'do so' test. *She worked, and did so as a waitress, I love you, but do so as a friend* Compare with:  *He passed and did so for dead*, *I took you and did so for granted*, *They left him and did so for dead*.

Comment: @Araucaria Mm, but I'd say it'd be possible to say, for instance, *she stayed, and did so in her room*, which would make *in her room* in *she stayed in her room* an adjunct too, so it seems that test doesn't quite work? Or am I missing something? Seeing that *in her room* in that example isn't an adjunct, but a complement, I mean?

Comment: @BillJ Ok – but what **kinds** of complement, and how do you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: Oops. Yes, the comp must be in the original phrase. Doesn't work well with verbs that can be used with no complements either.

Comment: @Araucaria  And what semantic category would they belong to? I don't _think_ the "do so" test works where the comp of the  prep is a predicative.